# MySQL split table amounts based on another table information

Tags: php, mysql, split

I need to split amounts in a table (transactions) accord to another related table information (bill_details).

Base table (transactions):

| ID | amount | document_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100.00 | 11 |
| 2 | 80.00 | 12 |
| 3 | 120.00 | 13 |

Another table (bill_details):

| ID | amount | document_id | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20.00 | 11 | A |
| 2 | 60.00 | 11 | B |
| 3 | 20.00 | 11 | C |
| 4 | 80.00 | 12 | D |
| 5 | 60.00 | 13 | E |
| 6 | 20.00 | 13 | F |
| 5 | 20.00 | 13 | G |
| 6 | 40.00 | 13 | H |

What I need:

| amount (splited from transactions) | description (from row in description) |
| --- | --- |
| 20.00 | A |
| 60.00 | B |
| 20.00 | C |
| 80.00 | D |
| 60.00 | E |
| 20.00 | F |
| 20.00 | G |
| 20.00 | H |

**Notes:** Sometimes the sum of 'bill_details' amount is not equal to the 'transactions' amount.
A bill can have 0+ transactions.

should I keep trying to do it in MySQL or should I use PHP?

Comment: your queston makes no sense as amount dorm result is the same as amiunt from bill so how comes the transaction into it

Comment: And what magic rule tells you the `H` is wrong and should be `20.00` rather than `E` being changed to `40.00`

Comment: What MySQL version you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bit complicate but in MySQL 8.0 you can use window function in next way:

```
SELECT 
    description,
    bill_details.amount + least(
        transactions.amount -
        SUM(bill_details.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY document_id ORDER BY bill_details.ID),
        0
    ) amount
    
FROM bill_details
JOIN transactions USING(document_id)
ORDER BY bill_details.ID
```

[Live SQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/4376b5ab39cade4d13ae91d798e7a0ac/)

Comment: Thanks you very much, you helped me a lot. I know my questions was not very clear, my english is very limited but somehow you got it.